# Trying to post a bitmap to facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to implement facebook in my application. Im able to post a title, a caption and a **link**, using this code:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", "TestingApp");
postParams.putString("caption","Testing");
postParams.putString("description","ImageFilter makes your day brighter!");
postParams.putString("picture","https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

But how am I supposted to post a **local** image?

I've already tried this code, but it gives a nullpointer exception!

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        postParams.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
```

Stacktrace:

```
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     com.example.facebooktesting.MainActivity$2.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:147)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1240)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)    
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-25 18:21:22.009: E/AndroidRuntime(22803):    at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

me/feed does not support uploading pictures, you should post to me/photos instead.

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

You should put the bitmap in the "source" parameter.

You can also just use this method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest%28Session,%20Bitmap,%20Callback%29